# Hudson Subversion Release Manager Plug-in

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, hudson, hudson-plugins

Has anyone ever tried the [Hudson Subversion Release manager](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Subversion+Release+Manager)plug-in?

I don't see the releases link shown in the page after installing the plug-in.

Answer (score 3):

Under the configuration of the job, you need to set up the following:

- Change your Source Control Management setting to "Subversion Release" (not just Subversion!)
- Check "This build is parameterized", and add a "List subversion tags". Point this to path on your SVN server which lists all of your tags.
- Check "Use Subversion Release Manager"

Answer (score 1):

This plugin only works with Non parameterized build , if you have amy pre SCM build script or any other build parameter passed as part of the svn url , nothing comes up in the release link

Answer (score 0):

Restart Jenkins on Linux will see the Releases link, my problem is it clocks forever when I click the link, nothing happens.